# How to view server connections of a session or workflow

Tags: session, workflow, informatica, informatica-powercenter

As an SQA, I need to verify that all connections associated with a set of workflows have been updated. How can I view all connections associated with a workflow? Is there a connection, or connections, assigned to individual workflows, or would I need to find the connections for each individual session? If so, how do I view the connection(s) of a session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be plenty connections used by a single session - that's very often the point of ETL and data integration. Those connections used in session (or sessions!) may be defined in this session. But a session can use parameter for the connection that will be replaced with some value defined in a parameter file. A parameter file can be defined on the session itself, or it can be defined for a workflow. Or there can be some external utility that stores the configuration and executes the workflow with a generated parameterfile that you will not find in the workflow definition at all.

There are some tools that would help you get all the connections for a session or all sessions in a workflow, but deriving the values for the parameters is more difficult. You need to know where they come from in your environment.

Please note that workflows and sessions hold the connection name only - where does it actually connect depends on the connection definition.

In addition, the very same workflow and sessions can be executed with different connection values, e.g. to perform the same set of operations on a different set of sources and/or targets.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Maciejg. Connection definitions can be found in Workflow Manager -> Connections -> Relational, right?
Also, is there a way to view the connection names that individual workflows or sessions hold?

Comment: Right, that's where the connections are. There's no simple way to check all the connections used by a workflow, however. Unless you use some external tool that does XML analysis. I'm using http://powercenter-xmlanalyzer.appspot.com/xmlAnalyzerSample - if you expand the Sources or Targets in a given session, you'll see Connection name (if a connectoin is used directly) or Connection variable (if a variable is used).